# Does a long running loop with async IO needs the LongRunning option?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have read that a long running task is considered one that blocks the thread, thus it need to be marked with the `LongRunning` option so the tasks scheduler prefer to assign a new thread to that task.

A task that have async IO is also considered long running?

Example:

```
//This method can run for hours
async Task ListenerLoop(CancellationToken Cancel, NetworkStream stream)
{
      while(!Cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
                var CancelTimeoutOrReadSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var TimeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ReadTimeout), CancelTimeoutOrReadSource.Token);
                var ReadTask = stream.ReadAsync(b, 0, b.Length, CancelTimeoutOrReadSource.Token);

                if (await Task.WhenAny(TimeoutTask, ReadTask) == TimeoutTask)
                {
                    CancelTimeoutOrReadSource.Cancel(); 
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    CancelTimeoutOrReadSource.Cancel(); 
                    //readed bytes count
                    c = ReadTask.Result;
                }

                //read 'c' bytes from array 'b'

                //Give time to other tasks to run (Is this correct?)
                await Task.Delay(5000);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no. For background reading try http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Also, you do not need the await Task.Delay at the end to give time for other work in an async-await scenario.

Regarding the longrunning option see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8304b44f-0480-488c-93a4-ec419327183b/when-should-a-taks-be-considered-longrunning?forum=parallelextensions